# Привязка текстового поля к чекбокс

Tags: wpf, xaml

Есть чекбокс и текстовое поле связанное с ним :

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=USDCheck, Path=IsChecked}" />
```

Таким образом если чекбокс не выбран то и текстбокс неактивен. Однако этого недостаточно если пользователь сначала ввел значение а потом передумал и снял чекбокс. Тогда текстовое поле уже неактивно но значение в нем присутствует. Добавляю в разметку

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=USDCheck, Path=IsChecked}" 
         Text="{Binding ElementName=USDCheck, Path=IsChecked}" />
```

Тогда текст в поле становиться или `True` или `False` в зависимости от того выбран чекбокс или нет. Если `True` его конечно можно поменять а наоборот нет. Вопрос - как заменить `True` или `False` на 0.00 ? т.е.  в случае снятия галочки с чекбокса текстбокс не только стал не активным но и принял значение 0.00 ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте триггеры, а если нужен буффер на предыдущее значение, берите и кастомите свой TextBox c DependencyProperty и блекджеком

Comment: @ParanoidPanda можно небольшой пример ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решается с помощью простого триггера

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=USDCheck, Path=IsChecked}">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=USDCheck, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="0.0" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогает. Если я активирую чекбокс и введу текст а потом сниму чекбокс то текст останется преждним.как на картинке в вопросе.

Comment: @Сергей должно все работать.

Comment: Разобрался. Действительно все работает.

Answer (score 2):

Ваша задача — это задача бизнес-логики, и следовательно, решать её надо на VM-уровне.

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding IsTextEnabled}" Value="{Binding Value}"/>
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsFieldEnabled}"/>
```

и в VM

```
bool isFieldEnabled;
public bool IsFieldEnabled
{
    get => isFieldEnabled;
    set
    {
        if (Set(ref isFieldEnabled, value))
        {
            IsTextEnabled = IsFieldEnabled;
            if (!IsFieldEnabled)
                Value = 0.0;
        }
    }
}
```